# Validating script pasted in a field

Tags: php, javascript

I want to add a textarea field to my website where users can paste a whole script into it and save it.

What I'm worried about is users trying to inject other code into the field.

This is how the script would look ... ID and hex would change but nothing else:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var advertvars_vars = {
             pubid: '00000000000', // publisher id
             bgcolor: '804296', // background color (hex)
             text: 'FFFFFF', // font-color (hex)
             test: true 
            };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/static/ad.js"></script>
```

My question is...Is there anyway of validating that the user is pasting valid code as above?

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: what do you mean by 'other code'?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask the user for those parameters (ID and hex) en then generate the correct output?

Comment: Stijn Janssen - I thought about that but I thought I would make it simple for the user and just ask them to paste the whole script.

Comment: If you let users paste script, it's technically a remote script injection. That is the feature you're looking for, so don't complain about *that it works*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is calling for trouble. No matter how thoroughly you validate, someone **will** come up with a way to inject something evil in the textbox. Never, ever, `eval()` or otherwise run something coming from user input directly. Just add a form where user can type the values for `pubid`, `color`, etc, validate them and then assemble the javascript chunk yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to get only ID and hex from user, validate and set these values on the server to the finally composed script.